# Does knockout not like html tag inside another one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, knockout.js

I am buiding a web page with knockout 3.0.
All I want to do is to create a bootstrap list with badge, see example and code below

[image]

However, when I do it in the knockout template binding like this

```
<script type="text/html" id="document-template">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: Caption">
               <span class="badge" data-bind="text:PageCount"></span>
    </li>
</script>
```

the page looks like, no span

[image]

If I move the span tag outside the li tag like this

```
<script type="text/html" id="document-template">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: Caption"></li>
    <span class="badge" data-bind="text:PageCount"></span>
</script>
```

I could see my span text - for sure it has wrong css

[image]

My question is 1) does knockout just not like one tag inside aonther one?
Or 2) did I do something wrong, if I am wrong, could you please give me some suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It is overwriting the contents of your LI element with the text binding. Just put two spans inside your LI:

```
<script type="text/html" id="document-template">
    <li class="list-group-item">
               <span class="badge" data-bind="text:Caption"></span>
               <span class="badge" data-bind="text:PageCount"></span>
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: your change works !  Thanks a lot.  Does the text bind of parent div overwrite the child html tags inside it?

Comment: Yes, it replaces the entire content of the parent div, hence your issue.

Answer (score 2):

This line...

```
<li class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: Caption">
```

replaces the following

```
<span class="badge" data-bind="text:PageCount"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Does the text bind of parent div overwrite the child html tags inside it?

Comment: Yes, the text binding overwrites the inner HTML, therefore your spans disappear.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me too, here my example:

before (in this button, the font awesome icon was overwritten, and just text was rendered):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="text:toggleButtonText(), enable:isShowAllRequired(), click:toggleIsShowAll"> 
      <i data-bind="css:getShowallIcon()"></i>
</button>
```

After (with the extra span suggested above, it renders icon + text):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="enable:isShowAllRequired(), click:toggleIsShowAll"> 
    <i data-bind="css:getShowallIcon()"></i>
    <span data-bind="text:toggleButtonText()"></span>
</button>
```